# Continuous random variable distribution probability

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

In a final exam, there are 300 students and one-third of them bring a water bottle. Suppose that for those who bring a water bottle, the chance that each of them leaves behind his/her water bottle in the examination room after the exam is 0.06.

a) What are the mean and standard deviation of the total number of water bottles left behind after the exam? Give your answers to 2 decimal places.

b) Using an appropriate approximation method, find the probability that 5 or less water bottles are left behind. Carry your answers from the previous part to at least 6 decimal places in your calculation here. Give you final answer to 4 decimal places.

c) Using an appropriate approximation method, at most how many water bottles will be left behind 84.13% of the time? Give your answer to the nearest integer.

So far, I have found the mean. I think it should be 300$\frac{1}{3}$(0.06) = 6. I got the standard deviation as 23.74 by doing $\sqrt{Var(X)}$ where Var(X)= E($X^{2}$) - $[E(X)]^{2}$. I'm pretty lost because I don't know how to determine which distribution to use. Any hints or help is appreciated.

Comment: If it is a proportion shouldn't the $\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}$ formula be used?

Comment: Let $C$ be a constant and $X$ a random variable. Then $Var(X+C)=Var(X)$. In this context that means that you have not to regard the students who haven´t take the bottle in class. If $X$ ist the random variable for the students who left behind the bottles then $X$ is binomial distributed as $X\sim Bin(100;0.06)$. The variance of a binomial distribution is well known.

Comment: Your standard deviation is right by the numbers, but it is $2.37$

Comment: Any ideas how to do b) and c)? I tried using the normal distribution, but got it wrong. I added P(X=0)+..+P(X=5) @callculus

Comment: @gofish Maybe you can use the normal distribution as an approximation.

$P(X\leq x)\approx\Phi\left( \frac{x+0.5-\mu}{\sigma} \right)$,

 where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. But one thumb rule for a good approximation is $n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)>9$. This is not the case here. It seems that it is not appropiate enough. Another idea I don´t have.

Comment: @shardulc: $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}.$ The formula $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ is for a binomial _proportion._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose they want you to find the binomial distribution of the
number $X$ of bottles left behind. That's $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=.06)$.
Then $\mu = E(X) = np = 6$ as you say, and $\sigma = SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 2.37.$

For part (b), you want 
$$P(X \le 5) = P(X \le 5.5) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le 
\frac{5.5 - 6}{2.37}\right) \approx P(Z \le -0.21) =\, ??,$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. You can get the probability from printed
tables of the standard normal CDF. Using 5.5 instead of 5.0 is called
the 'continuity correction' for the normal approximation.

The exact binomial probability can be found using software. Here is how
that looks using R statistical software. You should get close to 0.44
using the normal approximation.

```
pbinom(5, 100, .06)
## 0.4406927
```

Here is a plot of the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(100,.06)$ along with the
density function of the 'best fitting' normal distribution. (As @Callculus anticipates, the fit
isn't perfect, so don't expect to get *exactly* 0.44.)

[image]

In part (c), you want to find $k$ such that $P(X \le k) = 0.8413.$
I will leave that computation to you. After you 'standardize' you
will need to use the normal table 'backwards', looking in the body
of the table for 0.8413 (or 0.3413) depending on the style of
normal table you are using. Then find the corresponding z-value from the margins of the table, and
solve for $k.$ Just by eye from the plot above, I'd guess $k \approx 8.$